# A current is initiated in a wire sitting next to a magnet, north pole. Force on wire is up. Does a downward force on the magnet arise?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Wire is just left of the north pole and current is into the page and so the force on the wire is up (right hand rule, Lorentz force).  I'm looking for the equal-but-opposite reaction force - where is it?

Comment: There is a reaction force on the magnet which is usually not noticed.

Comment: See e.g. [Electromagnetically_induced_acoustic_noise_and_vibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetically_induced_acoustic_noise_and_vibration#General_explanation)

Comment: Merely stating that there is a "reaction force on the magnet which is usually not noticed" or pointing me to a Wikipedia page regarding noise and vibration (which had nothing about my particular question) is not satisfactory.   I plan to conduct experiments for myself, to find out.